# Remove the LF from the test file and leave the CRLF (batch, PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0

I have a .txt file in which some of the lines end with LF (there should not be a new line here), and the part ends with CRLF. How can I remove the LF and leave the CRLF?

This is my original file content:

[image: original]

I am trying the following code (doesn't work because it doesn't remove unnecessary line feeds (LF))

```
(Get-Content $path -Raw).Replace("(?!\r)\n"," ") | Set-Content $path -Force
```

This is my intended result

[image: what I want]

**For clarity, the intention is therefore, to replace all `LF` characters, which are not immediately preceded with a `CR` character, with a single space character.**

*P.S. Any PowerShell code must be compatible with version 2.0*

Comment: BTW, in `PowerShell`, I would probably try it more like this: `(Get-Content -Path $path -Raw) -Replace '(?<!\x0D)\x0A',' ' …`

Comment: I tried this `(Get-Content -Path $path -Raw) -Replace '(?<!\x0D)\x0A',' ' | Set-Content $path -Force` and everything is fine, except that I get an extra CRLF after each line. How can I get around this?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of PowerShell you are using, and preferably include its appropriate tag. We cannot guess that your version of PowerShell is not at least version 5, _(that included in Windows 10 versions and released for 5½ years)_, and which includes the `-NoNewLine` option with `Set-Content` you needed.

Comment: I know, but I need this to work on different machines, including outdated ones (since Windows 7). The question has been edited.

Comment: I've further edited your question to clarify because putting PowerShell 4, whilst it does exclude the `-NoNewLine` option with `Set-Content` in Version 5, does not tell your potential responders that this must be able to work on a default installation in [[tag:Windows-7]]

Comment: I highly recommend you to update your systems as [**Support for Windows 7 ended on January 14, 2020. If you are still using Windows 7, your PC may become more vulnerable to security risks.**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ww/microsoft-365/windows/end-of-windows-7-support)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to do something like this? This is assuming no whitespace actually exists on the end of each line:

```
@echo off
set "fd="
for /f "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do call set "fd=%%fd%%%%a "
(echo %fd:~0,-1%)>result.txt
```

You have both `powershell` and `batch-file` tags, hence a `batch-file` solution.

Answer (score 0):

[.replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0) doesn't accept regex like [-replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#replacement-operator) does.  And you're using negative lookhead `(?!)` instead of [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?<!)`.  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is useful for seeing what a regex expression does.  With raw strings, you may want the `-nonewline` option to set-content.

```
"12345`n56789`n09876`r`n" -replace "(?<!\r)\n", " "

12345 56789 09876
```

Comment: `-NoNewline` this is not supported on my system, is there any other way to block the addition of the CRLF?

Answer (score 0):

Normally [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content)
will break and stream lines on any combination of `CR`, `LF` or both `CRLF`.
You might prevent this with the `` -Delimiter "`r`n" `` parameter:

```
Get-Content $InPath -Delimiter "`r`n" |
ForEach-Object Replace "`n", " " |
Set-Content $OutPath
```

Tested using **Powershell version 7.1.3**

Comment: I assume you mean `ForEach-Object { $_.Replace("\`n", " ") }`.  Also, this will mistakenly take out the last `\`n`.

Comment: Or `ForEach-Object Replace -args "\`n", " "`

Comment: @js2010. Hmm, despite what the [`ForEach-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) documentation says about `-MemberName` and using `-ArgumentList`, the commands runs well for me (POSH version `7.1.3`). I guess this is because the arguments are static. "*Also, this will mistakenly take out the last*", note that `Get-Content` will *stream* each line (as I am not using the `-Raw` parameter), meaning that there aren't any `CrLf` left in the string array (and no `Lf` can be taken wrongly) which are restored again by the `Set-Content` cmdlet.

Comment: @js2010, Actually you might be right for `-MemberName`: The ``("`n", " ")`` part is probably seen as an positional `-ArgumentList` parameter (even it isn't stated in the document either). In other words, removing the parenthesis also works (updated in the answer).

Comment: Oh ok.  I was testing with ps 5.